# X Server for Windows?

Tags: ssh, windows-7

I'm going to accessing my ubuntu machine remotely from my windows machine through putty. Are there any suggestions for possible ways to get an X server running on my windows machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Install  [Xming](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Xming) and [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) in Windows.
- Have a terminal server running under Linux.
- Execute Xming under windows: double click the X icon.
- Execute Putty: configure it to connect your server Ip and to forward the X11 to your Windows machine IP.
- Login and run the Linux application.

**Source**: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=225898

Comment: Note that things that require root priveleges (sudo'ed apps) won't forward over X11 by default.  You need to copy your xauth token from your non-root user to root in order to forward them over X11

Comment: I just did it now and it worked like a charm! Awesome.

Comment: This method can only run a single Linux application on the remote Linux box and display on your local Windows box. But how to start a remote desktop session?

Answer (score 2):

you can run both ssh and X in cygwin

Answer (score 0):

You can see this step by step [tutorial](http://www.sharms.org/blog/2009/07/connecting-to-ubuntu-from-windows/) to access ubuntu from windows using **Putty and SSH**.

Also,to access ubuntu from windows,you can also install freesshd in windows.You can get freesshd [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freesshd.com%2F&rct=j&q=freesshd&ei=pUblTNrFC5DCvQO1oqmBDQ&usg=AFQjCNHxLQVUgHleBJthhYMQ59loDV9nMA&cad=rja)

**Alternate way**:

The alternate way is to install Team viewer on both systems..You can get team viewer [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/index.aspx)

[image]

It can even work behind firewall and proxies.

Comment: The tutorial link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to access ubuntu desktop from your windows machine. if my assumption is right there is lot of ways to do it:

1). in ubuntu enable 'Remote desktop' from 'Sytem'-->'Preferences'->'Remote desktop' menu. and then use a vnc client in windows.

2). Install NX server in ubuntu and use nxclient for windows in your windows system. I am using this method to access my ubuntu desktop from windows system.

Have a look at the features page: http://www.nomachine.com/features.php
   Check this url for downloads: http://www.nomachine.com/download.php