# Anything that converts GUI actions to commands to be sent to remote ubuntu via SSH?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, ssh, gui, putty

Is there anything that would allow me to run a GUI on client side of SSH(ie on windows)& that would convert the GUI actions made to corresponding commands to be sent via SSH client(in my case putty) to remote ubuntu server ? Also it could show me the corresponding commands that it sends via SSH. I dont have GUI installed on my ubuntu server so I am looking out for any tools that may be installed on the client(running windows 7) that communicates to ubuntu server via SSH.

Does anything like that exists ? Or may be a tool that helps me doing frequent actions via Putty more easily than me requiring to remember exactly how to accurately write all the ubuntu commands ?

Comment: do you want to transfer files or work with remote machine's gui? Are you asking for something like Remote Desktop?

Comment: I dont have a GUI on my remote ubuntu server so I want to install some GUI utility at my client(not the server) running windows 7.

Comment: Try pac manager is that your requirement

Comment: `ssh -X ...` does *exactly* what you're describing--an X Server runs on the client, and GUI applications installed in the server (which does not have to have an actual GUI installed, only certain minimal libraries) connect through the SSH connection to the X Server on the client and display their interfaces. Since Windows doesn't come with an X server or use X as its underlying GUI, you'll have to install some X server on the Windows system. See [X Server for Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13855/x-server-for-windows)

Comment: @EliahKagan : I want a GUI on the windows side to manage my remote ubuntu server which is without any GUI. So my GUI actions need to be converted to commands on windows machine itself & then sent to ubuntu server via SSH client like putty. I dont think that X server does that ? Does it ?\

Comment: @user01 With `ssh -X`, applications run on the (SSH) server, which you can connect to with PuTTY, and which doesn't need to have any GUI installed. The applications' graphical interfaces appear and are used on the client machine, which does have a GUI; they appear on the client machine's desktop. Every action performed on the GUI by the user of the client causes data to be transmitted through the SSH connection to the server, which then performs the appropriate tasks, just as if the same action were performed on a GUI application running "normally" on the server. Is that not what you need?